# 2D Array of JButtons Not Appearing

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jbutton

So I'm working an an assignment and I seemed to be stuck on a bug I can't seem to overcome. Essentially when trying to create a 10x10 grid, it isn't appearing while everything else (eg. title and menu) is when I'm running the application. Here's the essential part of what I've done so far

```
public class minesweeperGUI extends JFrame{

    private JFrame gameGUI;
    private JPanel board;
    private JButton[][] boardButtons = new JButton [10][10];

    public minesweeperGUI(){

        gameGUI = new JFrame("Enhanced Minesweeper"); //Title of the Window
        gameGUI.setVisible(true); //We want (true) to set it visible
        gameGUI.setSize(400,550); //400 550
        gameGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //This will close the frame when you press X. IMPORTANT
        gameGUI.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        gameGUI.setLayout(null);

        //Panel for minesweeper board
        board = new JPanel();
        GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(10, 10);
        board.setLayout(experimentLayout);
        board.setSize(400,550);

        for(int x=0;x<boardButtons.length;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<boardButtons[x].length;y++){

                boardButtons[x][y] = new JButton();
                board.add(boardButtons[x][y]);
                }
        }

        gameGUI.add(board);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        minesweeperGUI mainInterface = new minesweeperGUI();

    }
}
```

Any type of help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> gameGUI.setVisible(true); //We want (true) to set it visible

- yes but its should be last code line in  `minesweeperGUI()`, otherwise you added `JComponent`s to the already visible Swing Gui (missing notifier for automatical refresh, repaint)

---

> minesweeperGUI mainInterface = new minesweeperGUI();

- should be wrapped into `invokeLater`, more in Oracle trail `Initial Thread`
- class name should be `MinesweeperGUI`, search for `Java Namings Convention`

---

> gameGUI.setLayout(null);  and board.setSize(400,550);

- missing there `setBounds` for `board.setSize(400,550);` (placing `JPanel` to `JFrame`, because `JPanel` has zero `Dimension`)
- there no reason to use `null layout`, remove `gameGUI.setLayout(null);`

  1. override `getPreferredSize` for `private JPanel board;`
  2. remove code lines `gameGUI.setLayout(null);`  and `board.setSize(400,550);`
  3. add code line `pack()` before `setVisible(true)`, for proper sizing for `JFrame` (based on `getPreferredSize` for `private JPanel board;`)

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you, and for someone still learning GUI, this was very informative.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `gameGUI.setLayout(null);` call and move the next line to be after buttons adding

```
    gameGUI.setSize(400,550); //400 550
    gameGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //This will close the frame when you press X. IMPORTANT
    gameGUI.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    gameGUI.setVisible(true); //We want (true) to set it visible
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one Problem is that you mix up your instances...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    minesweeperGUI mainInterface = new minesweeperGUI();
}
```

makes a new Instance of your minesweeperGUI wich extends JFrame - so this simply makes a new JFrame...

but in your construktor you create another JFrame instance `private JFrame gameGUI;` and `gameGUI = new JFrame("Enhanced Minesweeper");` ...

i suggest you remove the private variable gameGUI (`private JFrame gameGUI;`) and use simply `this` for your layout...

```
//private JFrame gameGUI; //remove this one!
private JPanel board;
private JButton[][] boardButtons = new JButton [10][10];
public minesweeperGUI(){

    super("Enhanced Minesweeper"); //construktor from superclass
    this.setVisible(true); //use of this
    this.setSize(400,550); //use of this
    ...        

    //Panel for minesweeper board
    board = new JPanel();
    GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(10, 10);
    board.setLayout(experimentLayout);
    board.setSize(400,550);

    for(int x=0;x<boardButtons.length;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<boardButtons[x].length;y++){

            boardButtons[x][y] = new JButton();
            board.add(boardButtons[x][y]);
            }
    }
    this.add(board); //use of this

}
```

you don't **HAVE** to write `this.setXXX()` you can also simply write `setVisible(true)`for instance...